# recursive history search for tcsh shell

Tags: bash, shell, command-substitution, tcsh, csh

In bash shell, i generally use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to fuzzy search a command that i executed recently.
However the same doesn't seem to work for `tcsh` or `csh` shells.

I want to understand if/how to do the same mapping in `tcsh`/`csh` shells too.

Note: I saw somewhere that <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> has a similar effect, but it is not the same keybinding.
I would like to have <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> binding to do the same task on different shells.

Any leads are much appreciated. Thanks a bunch :) !!

Comment: Is this helpful: `bindkey '^R' i-search-back` ?

Comment: That is what i was looking for.. thanks :)